# What is correct way to include React Blueprint to React Starter Kit?

Tags: reactjs, react-starter-kit, blueprintjs

What is correct way to include BlueprintJS Css files to React-starter-kit?
I was able to do that in /src/components/Layout/Layout.js importing css file

```
import blueprintCss from '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css';
```

and on export

```
export default withStyles(normalizeCss, blueprintCss, s)(Layout);
```

Is this correct way or is there another one like with webpack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply `import '@blueprintjs/core/dist/blueprint.css';` should include the CSS file in your webpack build.

I don't know enough specifics about react-starter-kit to tell you more, but the simple import statement above is the traditional approach.